# How to change a Label text value by selecting a Combobox

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a site with the option to book a hotel.
The rooms are single, double and shared.
As you can see in the photo, I need to have a JavaScript code that can be used to change “the number of rooms” in the case of choosing a single and double rooms and “the number of persons” in the case of choosing a shared room.
The following code is taken from part of the WooCommerce plugin.
I put a section of the code containing the name of the label as well as the extension code that is associated with the booking form below.
Please help me on this. Code JavaScript should be written code that includes the option of a shared room (.includes("shared room")), because prices for each hotel or guesthouse are different.

"Because the site is managed by WordPress, you need to import the javascript code into the file Function.php.
These codes should be implemented on pages containing booking.php."

[image: hotel dropdown]

```
/* My JavaScript */
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $('select[id=wc_bookings_field_resource]').change(
                    function () {
                        var newText = $('option:selected', this).text();
                        if (newText.includes(Shared room) {
                            $('#').text('Number of Persons');//????
                        } else {
                            $('#').text('Number of Rooms');//????
                        }

                    }
                );
            }
        );
</script>



/* part of the WooCommerce */
<?php   

    private function persons_field() {
        // Persons field
        if ( $this->product->has_persons() ) {

            // Get the max persons now to use for all person types
            $max_persons = $this->product->get_max_persons() ? $this->product->get_max_persons() : '';

            if ( $this->product->has_person_types() ) {
                $person_types = $this->product->get_person_types();

                foreach ( $person_types as $person_type ) {
                    $min_person_type_persons = $person_type->get_min();
                    $max_person_type_persons = $person_type->get_max();

                    $this->add_field( array(
                        'type'  => 'number',
                        'step'  => 1,
                        'min'   => is_numeric( $min_person_type_persons ) ? $min_person_type_persons : 0,
                        'max'   => ! empty( $max_person_type_persons ) ? absint( $max_person_type_persons ) : $max_persons,
                        'name'  => 'persons_' . $person_type->get_id(),
                        'label' => $person_type->get_name(),
                        'after' => $person_type->get_description(),
                    ) );
                }
            } else {
                $this->add_field( array(
                    'type'  => 'number',
                    'step'  => 1,
                    'min'   => $this->product->get_min_persons(),
                    'max'   => $max_persons,
                    'name'  => 'persons',
                    'label' => __( 'Number of Persons/Rooms' , 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                ) );
            }
        }
    }

/* a part of Html */
<label for="wc_bookings_field_persons">Persons/Rooms:</label>
<input type="number" value="1" step="1" min="1" max="10" name="wc_bookings_field_persons" id="wc_bookings_field_persons"> 

<label for="wc_bookings_field_resource">Type of Rooms:</label>
<select name="wc_bookings_field_resource" id="wc_bookings_field_resource">
    <option value="20996">Single room (+€30,00 per day)</option>
    <option value="20997">Double room (+€40,00 per day)</option>
    <option value="21327">Shared room (+€20,00 per day)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What's the error? `if (newText.includes(Shared room))` should be `if (newText.includes('Shared room'))`, but otherwise the JavaScript looks fine.

Comment: can you add your html aswell? what is the id of the number of people field?

Comment: Hi, my problem is not "if (newText.includes('Shared room'))"!
I want to know, how can i write this Code clearly and where should i write. 
I am new in PHP and JavaScript and after writing the javaScript code in php, the program got the problem because I do not know how to write javaScript codes in php. And as you see in the code field of woocommerce, there is no ID for Label to change the label's name.

Comment: The label is formed in this section but, as you can see, no id is considered for it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was simply solved with a small search on the Internet.
To add javascript commands to the program, it is only necessary to add the code to the functions.php file.

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
                $(document).ready(
                    function () {
                        $('select[id=wc_bookings_field_resource]').change(
                            function () {
                                var newText = $('option:selected', this).text();
                                if (newText.includes('Shared room')) {
                                    $("label[for='wc_bookings_field_persons']").text('Persons:');
                                } else {
                                    $("label[for='wc_bookings_field_persons']").text('Rooms:');
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
        </script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```